# Is there a way to modify GC behavior for objects of my class

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

I have an application which is going to have millions of objects of a class that we own. We need our application to perform good on low memory machines; So we have a solution that lets us store and retrieve objects in file system on disk.

What I would like to implement is some sort of "shelving" of an object once its created and not used for so long,

One way is to destory/re-construct; but I heard GC moves long living objects to Gen 2 Heap; Is there any way I can tell GC that for so and so types of object, the Gen 2 heap should be replaced by something else ?

Comment: No, in very simple terms, the GC will check if an object has a root reference, it it does it gets promoted up the generations. One suggestion is if you make you classes structs (Value Types) then they will live on the thread stack and wont be subject to GC.

Comment: I don't really care if GC takes care of it or else. My only goal is when an object is being promoted to Gen 2, I want to trap it, clone it into file system and destroy it; and when the object is being used; it should be reconstructed from the file system. Kind of like how OS virtual memory does.

Comment: Why do you think that you can store-retrive data from disk faster than OS pageing?

Comment: Because I think dumb OS is not handling the Job well.. and customers are telling about the OutOfMemoryException they are getting. And most of the objects are not used they are simply dumped. Only select few are going to be "resurrected" back into memory.

Answer (score 2):

I did a bit of research and starting with .Net 4 you can use [ETW to detect garbage collection ETW events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764.aspx):

> Event tracing for Windows (ETW) is a tracing system that supplements
>   the profiling and debugging support provided by the .NET Framework.
>   Starting with the .NET Framework 4, [garbage collection ETW events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356162.aspx)
>   capture useful information for analyzing the managed heap from a
>   statistical point of view. For example, the GCStart_V1 event, which is
>   raised when a garbage collection is about to occur, provides the
>   following information:

- **Which generation of objects is being collected**.
- What triggered the garbage collection.
- Type of garbage collection (concurrent or not concurrent).

To start off with I recommend you take a quick view at the Managed Heap using the CLR Profiler. If you're working with millions of objects then I have a suspicion the time it takes serializing objects to disk will be too much overhead.

One last bit of advice is to release your application with Minimum Hardware Requirements so you dont have to worry about this.

Comment: Thanks, Here is the fun part.  Most of our customers can afford this $30 software but cannot afford to go to Best-Buy and pay them $89.95 + Tax to install a $32 memory module in their computers.... But answering your comment about the overhead... Most of the objects serialized to disk would not be used.